# Samba and Windows and i am unable to access the share folder form windows

Tags: samba

I have created a share directory in the same configuration file 
like this

```
[priciliashare]
comment=sharing my entire home directory
writable=yes
path=/home/pricilia
write list = test
browseable = Yes
create mask = 0775
create public = yes
```

i have this error when i try to access it from windows

Windows cannot access the \ip address\sharename contact your network administrator

Answer (score 0):

Did you
service smbd restart (on debian distributions)
service samba restart (on others)

otherwise setting on windows
in your windows configuration

Internet network\network and sharing\advanced parameter

Enable network discovery
Enable file and printer sharing
Enable password protected sharing

If that's not enough there are other settings of windows Explorer but who are can be already activated. Let me know